# Unable to view WPF browser

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

Facing a problem with some of the users that cannot view my system but somehow most of them are able to view it.

I have attached a screen shot of the error that some of them get. This error was caught in the constructor of the home page.

Seeing that on the screen shot it also complains about a method called `FillDataGrid()`, below is also a piece of code to fill the grid when the program starts up.

[image]

```
public void FillDataGrid()
{

    //try
    //{
        //Connection String
        String config = Properties.Settings.Default.ConnStr;
        //ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["IMS.APP.IM.ISMAssetControl.Properties.Settings.ConnSt"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(config);

        //Opening Connection String and fetching the query
        conn.Open();

        String cmdString;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(config);  

        cmdString = "execute sp_returnAllAssets";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdString, con);
        //cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        //Here first we loaded Employee database table in a DataTable object and then bind it to the DataGrid’s ItemsSource property.
        dt = new DataTable(cmdString);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        int i = dt.Rows.Count;
        grdAssetSummary.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;

    //}
    //catch (SqlException ex)
    //{
    //    MessageBox.Show("error");
    //}
}
```

Comment: Did you read the message on the screenshot you posted ??? "... An error occurred during the logon process"... Does all of your users have access to the database ?

Comment: users don't have direct access to the database but however they are able to read and write using the UI.
"Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=DBAssetControl;User ID=ismuser;Password=ismuser"
this is my connection string therefore using this string users gain access to the database.
The weird part of this is that only 2 pc's out of 20 are not able to view.

Answer (score 0):

The users that are facing this error don't have access to the Database. You can check the Database and the Database Server permissions.

You probably are using a **LAN Group / Active Directory** to authenticate, and then Windows Authentication I assume. If not, the access should be granted to users.

Even if they have access, You can check if they have access to execute the Stored procedure `execute sp_returnAllAssets`

Comment: users don't have direct access to the database but however they are able to read and write using the UI. "Data Source=myServer;Initial Catalog=DBAssetControl;User ID=ismuser;Password=ismuser" this is my connection string therefore using this string users gain access to the database. The weird part of this is that only 2 pc's out of 20 are not able to view.